# Why sum of divisors of a natural number $n$ including $1$ and $n$ can't be $75$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

**So this is the actual problem statement:**

Let $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, ...,x_{k}$ be the divisors of a positive integer $n$ (including $1$ and $n$). If $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + ... + x_{k} = 75$, then $\Sigma^{k}_{i=1} \frac{1}{x_{i}} = ?$

Undoubtedly the solution for this problem would be $\frac{75}{n}$ . But the actual problem is the problem statement is considered to be controversial since it is said that sum of divisors of a positive integer cannot be 75 .

So my question is , can it be proved that sum of divisors of a positive integer can't be 75 ?

Comment: Sure.  Since $n$ is included, all you need to do is check all of the possibilities from $1$ to $74$.  If it doesn't happen there, it can't happen at all.

Comment: The sum of divisor functions is multiplicative, so either $n=p^k$ with $p$ prime and $1+p+\cdots+p^k=75$ or $n=p^iq^j$ with $(1+p+\cdots+p^i)(1+q+\cdots+q^j)=75.$ But $5$ cannot be written as $1+p+\cdots+p^i,$ so the only factorization possible is $75=25\cdot 3.$ But no $q^j$ gives $1+q+\cdots+q^j=25.$

Comment: If I am not wrong, you got this controversy from Bhannat Maths YouTube channel?

Comment: @ADITYADAS absolutely mate ✌️